# JUnit 5 test case not executed

Tags: java, maven, netbeans-8, maven-surefire-plugin, junit5

I created this test in a new clean Maven project in NetBeans 8.2:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class JUnit501Test {

    @Test
    void firstTest() {
        fail("epicly");
    }
}
```

If I run the tests, the log shows

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running JUnit501Test
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

My pom.xml contains this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

What could cause JUnit 5 to ignore the test method?

Update: I added the surefire plugin, here is the full pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.timeshuttle</groupId>
    <artifactId>Junit5Test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>5.0.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Output changed to:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results:

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.672s
Finished at: Mon Oct 16 16:19:04 CEST 2017
Final Memory: 6M/15M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1:test (default-cli) on project Junit5Test: There are test failures.

Please refer to F:\Sandbox_Java\justin\Junit5Test\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
There was an error in the forked process
org.apache.maven.surefire.report.RunListener.testSetStarting(Lorg/apache/maven/surefire/report/ReportEntry;)V
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
org.apache.maven.surefire.report.RunListener.testSetStarting(Lorg/apache/maven/surefire/report/ReportEntry;)V
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:673)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:535)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:280)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:245)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1124)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:954)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:832)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
-> [Help 1]
```

And the surefire-reports folder contains two ".dump" files. Content of the first one:

```
# Created on 2017-10-16T16:17:32.959
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.maven.surefire.report.RunListener.testSetStarting(Lorg/apache/maven/surefire/report/ReportEntry;)V
    at org.junit.platform.surefire.provider.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeSingleClass(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.surefire.provider.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.surefire.provider.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:373)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:334)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:119)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:407)
```

Comment: Is the folder structure correct?

Comment: As nullpointer hints at, I'd suspect that the surefire plugin would listen for `org.junit.Test` annotations but you're using `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` hence the tests are not recognized.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make sure your `maven-surefire-plugin` is configured appropriately as:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version> <!-- Specific due to memory leak in 2.20 -->
    <dependencies>
         <!--Custom provider and engine for Junit 5 to surefire-->
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
             <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
             <version>1.0.1</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
             <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
             <version>5.0.1</version>
         </dependency>
     </dependencies>
     <configuration>
         <argLine>${argLine}</argLine>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and you don't need the engine as dependencies, so you can remove this from your `<dependencies>` tag :-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

***Note***: The official documentation of the Junit5 about [running tests with maven](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven) specifies using surefire 2.19.1 due to a memory leak in the 2.20 release version of the plugin.

Comment: Should you use version 1.0.1 of junit-platform-surefire-provider?

Comment: @Mika Updated with latest versions of dependencies. Was in progress. Thanks

Comment: Many thanks! It works with version 2.19.1. With 2.20.1 of the surefire plugin, I get the dump files.

Comment: Absolutely true, the 2.20.1 version fails as well. Reverted to 2.19.1

Comment: Just confirmed, same problem with 2.22.1

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solve by changing the language of the environnement's execution.

Try all commands:

```
- apt install locales-all
- update-locale LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8 LANGUAGE
- update-locale LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8
- update-locale LANG="fr_FR.UTF-8" LANGUAGE="fr_FR"
- dpkg-reconfigure locales
- apt-get update >/dev/null
- apt-get install -y locales >/dev/null
- echo "fr_FR UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen
- locale-gen fr_FR.UTF-8
- export LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
- export LANGUAGE=fr_FR:fr
- export LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8
```

Comment: How exactly does changing the locale to French help run Junit testcases?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).